# CORS Ionic 3 Post Requests

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I keep receiving the error below when I use Ionic Serve...

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

It only occurs with "post" request. The "get" requests I have work with no error. I've seen documentation for proxy's but I was not looking to go that route. I'm currently using the CORS Chrome plugin as a workaround right now, but will be shipping to mobile soon (Ionic view) for testing, which I believe I will still run into the CORS issue using Ionic View.

I have control of the API/server - using nginx.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This article explains how you can solve CORS issues on production Ionic app: https://hackernoon.com/a-practical-solution-for-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-issues-in-ionic-3-and-cordova-2112fc282664

Answer (score 1):

Cors will not affect to mobile phone. The issue is in POST method in web view. In Post methods Browser send OPTIONS Request for security Purpose. It should handle in API. I used ASP.NET WEB API When Using localhost I Used Two Methods for post in Same Name but it's not proper way for doing this. You need to handle in Configuration to Igonre this. If you have API without parameters add headers "content-type x-www-form-urlencoded" to you request header. If there are parameters. use another method without parameters using same name.(Method overloadin). But when you are using livehost don't forget to remove redundant methods.